# How to modulo one value with a range of other values?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, range, modulo

I'm populating a list with lines from a text document. The text document is a log file including 108 lines(entries) that repeat a few hundred times.

I'm using a For loop to populate the list, however I only need the first 65 lines.
Is there a way for the For loop to skip lines 66-108? I was thinking of using continue as shown in the code below, using modulo of the line numbers that I wish to skip.
Is there a way to use 'if modulo' with a range or will I need to have an 'if modulo' statement for every line I wish to skip?

```py
file = open('test.txt')
lines = file.readlines()
data = list()
for line in lines:
    if loopcount % range(66,108) == 0: #
        loopcount += 1
        continue
    loopcount += 1
    data.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file = open('test.txt')
lines = file.readlines()
data = list()
loopcount = 0
for line in lines:
  if loopcount % 108 < 65:
    data.append(line)
  loopcount += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
next_loop = False
file = open('test.txt')
lines = file.readlines()
data = list()
for line in lines:
    not_read = range(66,108)
    #test every num in the list
    for i in not_read:
        if loopcount % i == 0: 
            loopcount += 1
            next_loop = True
            break
    if next_loop:
        next_loop = False
        continue
    loopcount += 1
    data.append(line)
```

Comment: I like the idea, but unfortunately the continue will continue the new nested for loop (for i instead of for line)